# 「希望」の使い方・意味、類似表現

Tags: meaning, nuances

can anyone explain how do i use kibou in a sentence.
I wrote this sentence in my assignment.

私は卒業したあと、やりたいと思う仕事を見つける事を希望しています。 
My teacher corrected this sentence as

私は卒業したあと、やりたいと思う仕事を見つけたい。

I don't understand how should I use the word kibou in a sentence. What exactly does kibou mean and in what situation should i use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt is grammatical, but I think your teacher thought it was unnecessarily grandiose and stiff. (I think you already know the difference between [wago-and-kango](/questions/tagged/wago-and-kango).) Although we see 希望 used in songs and documentary videos all the time, 希望 is not a word we use on a regular basis. When you want to say "I hope so" or such in a daily situation, usually you should use ～たい, ～たいと思う, ～(だ)といいですね, ～れば良いと思います, etc.

Still, you can use 希望 when you seriously declare your choice. It's perfectly fine to say 私の将来の希望は教師になることです or 将来看護師になることを希望しています in an interview or such. If you have a chance to [write a Japanese curriculum vitae](https://blog.gaijinpot.com/write-japanese-resume/), you may see 本人希望記入欄. Japanese high school students often fill a form called 進路希望調査 to tell teachers their intended future course.

Comment: Okay... I got it now. Thank you so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

希望しています is a formal expression (ex. used in a job interview).

In a casual conversation, したい is natural.